# Add character after two character spaces from right to left

Tags: php, string, numbers, substr

I have time stored in my database. Here is an example of a time:

`800` or `1000`

the first one is 8:00 and the second one is 10:00. I want to add a semicolon `:` after the second character starting to count from the right to left. how can i do this in php?

here is what i tried:

```
$realTime = substr_replace($oldtime,":", 2, -strlen($oldtime));
```

but it started from the left but i need it to start counting from the right. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php):

> If **start** is negative, the replacing will begin at the **start**'th character from the end of string.

So use a negative number:

```
$realTime = substr_replace($oldtime,":", -2, -strlen($oldtime));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it with a regex

```
$newtime = preg_replace('#^(.*)([0-9]{2})$#','$1:$2',$oldtime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to have different formulas based on the length and use a case statement.

```
Update foo 
   set oldtime= case when length(oldtime) = 4 then  
                     concat(substr(oldtime,1,2),':',substr(oldtime,3,2))
                     when length(oldtime) = 3 then 
                     concat(substr(oldtime,1,1),':',substr(oldtime,2,2)) 
                end
```

[Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82367/1/0)